How does the recovery from the stunning effect of the Lightning spell work in the following turns?
In the description of the Lightning spell (Magic, pg. 196), it says a wounded target might be stunned and it describes how the test goes and how to recover from it. It goes as the excerpt below:

If the target is wounded, he must make a HT roll, at -1 per 2 HP suffered, or be stunned. He may attempt a HT roll each turn thereafter to recover.

That last sentence it's what giving my group some trouble. "He may attempt a HT roll each turn thereafter to recover." The initial stun has a penalty to their HT roll of -1 for each 2 HP of damage suffered. Some argue that the HT roll for the recovery of the stun would have the same penalty, while others say that it states a pure HT roll without any penalty.
Let's say a wizard hits a warrior wearing metal armor with the Lightning spell for 19 points of damage, due to electrical properties of the spell, it reduces its metallic DR to 1, causing 18 points of damage to the aforementioned warrior. They now roll a HT-9 roll (-1 per 2 HP of damage) and fail. Next turn, the warrior will either have to roll another HT-9 roll (high chance of failure) or an unmodified HT roll (high chance of recovery). This detail can clearly affect the outcome of a combat.

The recovery roll is vs unmodified HT. The rule in the Lightning spell is an abbreviated version of the full GURPS rules for electric shocks on pp. 432-33 of the Basic Set. That mentions HT rolls to recover several times without any hint of modifiers.
If GURPS rules don't say something, one should assume the omission is deliberate unless that doesn't make sense, or the GM disagrees. See this question on interpretation
